# Matching entries against category custom field

Tags: categories, relations, relatedto

I have two channels, `pages` and `products` and category groups for `categories` and `regions`.

The `pages` entry type has a field where you can select entries from `products` based on their `category` and `region`.

The `products` entry type has fields for `category`, `region`, and `postcode`.

The `regions` category has a table field with a column for the region `name` and its `postcode`.

So at the moment I have code that displays product entries based on what's selected in the `categories` and `regions` fields.

```
{% set relations = [
    'and',
    categories ? { targetElement: categories }, {# a list of category IDs #}
    regions ? { targetElement: regions } {# a list of region IDs #}
] | filter(o => o) %}

{# Include #}
{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .section('products')
    .orderBy('RAND()')
    .relatedTo(relations)
    .all() 
%}
```

Now I also need to include `product` entries whose `postcode` matches that of the `region` that's been selected.

I know it's probably going to include something like `targetElement: regions, field: 'postcodes.postcode'` and `sourceElement` but I can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: It's a normal table field? That's going to be difficult, table fields are difficult to filter by. Why is it a table field – are there multiple `name` + `postcode` rows in a single region category?

Comment: @MoritzLost yeah there can be multiple postcodes in a single region. Australia's a big place ;)